# jQuery. Автозамена кириллических сиволов на латинские

Tags: jquery

В одном из проектов нужно было сделать автоматическую замену кириллических символов на латинские. Как это реализовать на jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение попроще:

```
function translit(s) {
    var map = {
        'а': 'a',
        'б': 'b',
        'в': 'v',
        'г': 'g',
        'д': 'd',
        'е': 'e',
        'ё': 'yo',
        'ж': 'zh',
        'з': 'z',
        'и': 'i',
        'й': 'y',
        'к': 'k',
        'л': 'l',
        'м': 'm',
        'н': 'n',
        'о': 'o',
        'п': 'p',
        'р': 'r',
        'с': 's',
        'т': 't',
        'у': 'u',
        'ф': 'f',
        'х': 'kh',
        'ц': 'c',
        'ч': 'ch',
        'ш': 'sh',
        'щ': 'shch',
        'ы': 'i',
        'э': 'e',
        'ю': 'yu',
        'я': 'ya',
        'ь': "'"
    };

    return s.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(map).join('|'), 'g'), function(c) {
        return map[c];
    });
}

console.log( translit('текст на русском языке') );
```

**ДЕМО** для автозамены с учетом регистра: http://jsfiddle.net/wtyyLcgo/.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, код, который сделает эту работу. Конечно можно переделать этот код на использование keyup, но так нужно учитывать больше нюансов работы с клавиатурой, а этот вариант работает в при любых клавиатурных событиях.

```
$("input[name*=Name]:not([name*=Main])").focusout(function (e) {
    var englishchars = ["a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "e", "yo", "zh", "z", "i", "y", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "f", "kh", "c", "ch", "sh", "shch", "i", "e", "yu", "ya", "'"];
    var slavicchars = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ы", "э", "ю", "я", "ь"];
    var t = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var word = new Array();
    $.each(t.split(""), function(key, val) {
        var verified = String.fromCharCode(e.wich).match( /[^а - яё]/);
        if (verified) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var russiancharindex = jQuery.inArray(val, slavicchars);
            if (russiancharindex >= 0) {
                var englishcharindex = englishchars[russiancharindex];
                word.push(englishcharindex);
            } else {
                word.push(val);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return word;
    });
    $(this).val(word.join("").replace(",", ""));
});
```

Comment: @andrey.shedko Я полагаю замечание #tutankhamun справедливо. Речь идет не о праве задающего отвечать на собственный вопрос, что действительно правилами StackOverflow не запрещается, но даже поощряется. Дело в том, что ваш вопрос сформулирован недостаточно понятно. В нем не хватает контекста и примера исходного кода, из которого была бы очевидна ваша проблема. Между прочим, по правилам StackOverflow ваш вопрос следовало бы закрыть по причине неясности формулировки и невозможности дачи однозначного ответа.

Comment: Если бы @tutankhamun задал вопрос без неуместного ёрниченья, получил бы адекватный ответ, а так каков вопрос - таков ответ.